# Visual Studio 2008 Professional vs VS 2008 Team System

Tags: visual-studio

I've been using the trial edition of Visual Studio 2008 Team System to develop projects and work with my client's Team Foundation Server.  I am using the Team Explorer integration / source control plugin.

My trial is expiring and I'm having trouble finding information on what exactly I need to purchase.  I don't need to actually run a TFS server myself, but I do need the ability to connect to my clients and get/put files, and the integration with Team Explorer in VS is really nice, hence I'd rather not have to use an external 3rd party tool.

Do I need Team System to accomplish this or does Visual Studio 2008 Professional have the same TFS Plugin, and if so does it work the same?

I can't believe I'm having such a hard time finding the differences between the versions... if anyone has a good resource that'd be nice before I shell out $3,000 on something I don't need.  I develop mainly ASP.NET Solutions if that matters.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Studio 2008 Product Comparison Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en)

> I don't need to actually run a TFS server myself, but I do need the ability to connect to my clients

Whoever is running TFS should procure CALs (Client Access License) so that any client that works with this server is covered. I believe you buy them separately per client machine (somewhat around 400$ each). Also VS Team System editions have one or two CALs included. That may be or may not be worth it for you.

And yes, you can access TFS from VS 2008 Pro, just need to install the integration plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is possible at all for you, but if you can, I would wait for [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/products/2010/default.mspx) (to be released in march 2010). Not only is it a better product than VS2008 but also they have simplified the versioning/licensing part, also [Team Foundation Server 2010 Basic](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/10/01/tfs-2010-for-sourcesafe-users.aspx) may be suitable for your source control needs.

If you want to take a look, you can [download the beta versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx) of VS2010 and TFS2010.

Comment: Yeah I'd really like to do that, but I'm not sure I can wait.  I have to have something that will reliably connect to my client's TFS Server now.  Do you know if VS 2010 has a TFS Source Control Plugin for it that connects to TFS 2008?

Comment: With the appropriate preparation, TFS2010 can be connected to from VS2008. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/10/19/tfs-2010-compatibility-with-older-clients.aspx

Comment: I mean the other way around.  I was saying if I got the VS2010 Beta now and waited for VS2010 to be released, I'd need to be able to connect to my client's TFS2008 Server in the mean time.

Comment: It seems that you can do that too: http://geekswithblogs.net/hinshelm/archive/2009/05/18/connecting-vs2010-to-tfs-2008.aspx